# Eclipse: Compiling A Plugin For Java 1.5: "Columns For Eclipse"

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I decided to give Eclipse (Eclipse 3.7.2 ) a chance because of the plugin ["Columns For Eclipse"](http://columns4eclipse.sourceforge.net/).  The IDE I would like to migrate away from ( Visual Slickedit ) has spoiled me with sophisticated column editing features and this plugin has most of them, whereas the default column editing features in Eclipse are too basic for me.

I tried the plugin out at home and I really like it.   However, the machine I use at work runs on Java 1.5 and the plugin requires Java 1.6.

I would like to try recompiling the plugin under Java 1.5, as my job uses WebLogic 9.2 which runs on Java 1.5.   I don't want to risk compatibility issues by setting up my computer to run on Java 1.6

I have the source code, but it didn't come with directions on how to compile the plugin.  It isn't structured in a Maven project.

I'm 100% new to Eclipse so I was wondering if someone could give me step by step instructions for compiling (and installing ) my own copy of the plugin under Java 1.5.

Alternately, is it possible to set up Eclipse 3.7.2 to run on Java 1.6 but always compile in Java 1.5?

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building and installing the plugin without an existing build script would be quite complicated. For your second option, you can setup the compiler compliance level for the entire IDE:

[image: IDE Compiler settings]

Or alternatively, you could set it up on a project-by-project bases (Right click project, Properties->Java Compiler).

Comment: This doesn't stop you using APIs only available in Java 6 - I got bitten by this problem years ago.

Comment: Perception, SteveD, thanks for the incredibly useful and fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run Eclipse with Java 6, but use a Java 5 JDK as the default for compilation and runtime. You need to configure Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

You can also use Java 6 as the development/runtime and set the compiler compliance level to 1.5 (same as 5), but that's a bit dangerous as it doesn't stop you using APIs only available in Java 6; it only enforces language syntax.